# Looking for a 'method list' addin for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, add-in

I'm looking for a code navigation addin for Visual Studio 2008:

1. Press a keyboard shortcut to invoke a **popup** window that shows a **list** of methods of the **current** .cs file.
2. In the popup window the input focus auto sets to an input box where you can filter the method list as you type.
3. Press  to jump to the selected method.

That's all. When using [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi) there is a add-in called experts which does this and it's very productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has the functionality (<kbd>Alt+\</kbd>)

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thank you Dan, I heard good things about ReSharper, however, it small, lightweight addin will be better....